# Script work on localhost but not on server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this script

```js
$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("" + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html(JSON.stringify(response, null, 4));
}, "jsonp");
$.ajax({
    url: "http://ipinfo.io/json",
    success: function(response) {
        var pais = (response.country);
        if(pais=='BR') {
            //do something //
        }
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    statusCode: {
        429: function() {
            alert( "Number of tries exceeded" );
        }
    }
});
```

It's should get the ip of the user , it's works on localhost but when i upload it to the server it's not working..
Any suggestions?

Comment: are you getting any console errors in the Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: I know sometimes the URI can influence how it is resolved.  So, in some cases, the www. or lack of it changes how a page is rendered.  Not sure, but a hopeful suggestion ...

Comment: Your first call is to `http://ipinfo.io` which returns an HTML page. Your second call clearly shows you meant `http://ipinfo.io/json`

Comment: As @Wainage said check the URL $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {....  May be you have to change to http://ipinfo.io/json

Comment: Tried now anything you said but still not working :(

Comment: My website has SSL if it's matter